# Testing .vue components (Browserify, jasmine, vueify). Why do I need a wrapper div?

Tags: vue.js

I have finally been able to test .vue components the way I want to, however, I'm a little confused by a couple of things I had to add in order to get it working - any explanations would be great.  This is testing child components too.

Using the [vueify-template 1.0](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/browserify/tree/1.0), I altered the Hello.vue to be this

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <child></child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import Child from './Child.vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Hello World!'
    }
  },

  components: {
    Child
  }
})
</script>
```

Child looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="child">
    Child Content
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({

})
</script>
```

Now I can test these the way I want to with:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Hello from '../../src/components/Hello.vue'

describe('Hello.vue', () => {
  it('should render correct contents into el', () => {
    var mount = document.createElement('div');
    const vm = new Hello({
      el: mount,
    });
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.hello h1').textContent).toBe('Hello World!')
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.hello .child').textContent.trim()).toBe('Child Content')
  })
})
```

Now - a few questions if anyone has time to answer, I'm quite new to Vue & ES6 etc. so apologies if they're obvious!

1. I had to do the `export default Vue.extend({ .... })` before I was able to mount the components in my test. Does this matter? The app seems to perform identically so I'm not really sure what's going on here.
2. The main gotcha was that in my `<template>` if I didn't have the correctly named wrapper div class (e.g. `<div class="child">`) then *nothing* would be generated into the vm.$el . Oddly (to me) if I have exactly the same test, but don't include the `<child></child>` tag, then the `vm.$el` will be at least created... so I'm somewhat confused.
3. Is this an *evil* way to test? Am I fighting the framework?

Thanks for any and all pointers - I hope this isn't too generic a question for SO.